# Error in featuretools entity set

Tags: featuretools

I got the following error message when I define entity set with featuretools:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'

Here's my code:

```
import featuretools.variable_types as vtype 

es = ft.EntitySet(id="Policy")
es = es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id="Policy", dataframe='policy_df',index='Policy_no',variable_types={'Policy_no':vtype.Categorical})
```

Anyone faced same issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the argument `dataframe='policy_df'`. The dataframe should be a Pandas `DataFrame` object not a string. 
`